# Python scraper not returning full html code on some subdomains

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am throwing together a Walmart review scraper, it currently scrapes html from most Walmart pages without a problem. As soon as I try scraping a page of reviews, it only comes back with a small portion of the page's code, mainly just text from reviews and a few errant tags. Anyone know what the problem could be?

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
    'Referer': 'https://www.walmart.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows',
    }
cookie_jar = {
    '_pxvid': '35ed81e0-cb1a-11ec-aad0-504d5a625548',
}
product_num = input('Enter Product Number: ')
url2 = ('https://www.walmart.com/reviews/product/'+str(product_num))
r = requests.get(url2, headers=headers, cookies=cookie_jar, timeout=5)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Many pages load content dynamically (via Javascript) after the the browser loads the initial HTML. If this is the case, you won't be able to scrape the content using `requests`.

Comment: Thanks this definitely explains it!

Answer (score 0):

As larsks already commented, some content is loaded in dynamically, for example if you scroll down far enough.
BeautifulSoup or requests don't load the whole page, but you can solve this with Selenium.

What Selenium does is it opens your url in a script-controlled web browser, it lets you fill out forms and also scroll down. Below is a code example on how to use Selenium with BS4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# Search on google for the driver and save it in the path below
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe")
# for Chrome it's: driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

# Here you open the url with the reviews
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
driver.maximize_window()

# This function scrolls down to the bottom of the website
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")

# Now you can scrape the given website from your Selenium browser using:
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

This solution assumes that the reviews are loaded in through scrolling down the page. Of course you don't have to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the site, it's personal preference. Let me know if it helped.